# In my Blazor Server Side app, I want to run a code when the user leaves a razor page and changes to another page. How can I do that?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, razor-pages

I have following use case:
I have a razor page where a user can connect to a remote machine and monitor its process values. When he enters the related page the values will be read cyclic from the remote machine automatically. (With OnInitialized())

I want that, when the user changes to another page, the cyclic reading is stopped or paused. Currently it is continuing in the background.
(The data does not to be logged anywhere)

I can start the reading action when user opens the page with following code. I need a similar event for leaving the page, so that I can run the code for stopping or pausing the cycling reading. How can I do that?

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{      
  // starting cycling reading when page entered
  Read_cyclic_values();
}

public void Read_cyclic_values()
{
  // code for cycling reading in connection with a scoped service
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm maybe the IDisposable interface could be of some use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
@implements IDisposable
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

//Your HTML

@code
{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
    // Subscribe to the event
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged += LocationChanged;
        Read_cyclic_values();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    void Read_cyclic_values()
    {
    // code for cycling reading in connection with a scoped service
    }

    void LocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    //Do what you need to do to stop the cycle
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
    // Unsubscribe from the event when your component is disposed
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= LocationChanged;
    }
}
```

I think alternativly you could also just define the Cycle breaker in the Dispose